# How to adjust the width of a textbox depending on browsers using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser

I have a `textbox` in a form. I have given `style="width: 370px;”` While browsing in Firefox its alignment is correct with all other fields in this form. But in IE It's need to increase little more. i.e. `380px`.

SO how I will give the `width` to that text box depending on the browsers? I know it's possible. But I don't know how it is?

Does anyone know this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using JQuery, you can use jquery.browser to detect if the browser is IE (or any number of other well documented methods of browser detection. then if IE, set the side
$document.getElementByID(formelement).css(width).

Although I'd suggest looking further into why your form elements don't align in IE, and fix that instead of dynamically resizing your form elements based on the viewing browers.

Comment: `$.browser` is deprecated, please don't use it. Use conditional CSS as mentioned elsewhere in this thread, or try using `$.support`

Answer (score 0):

Why not [conditional CSS](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=conditional+css)?

Answer (score 0):

On js `document.write(navigator.appCodeName);`

On php `echo array_shift(explode(' ', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));`

Using these you can switch css, but have you ever looked in to css framework like `Blueprint` css

It contains something like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="blueprint/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="blueprint/print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" href="blueprint/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" /><![endif]-->
```

You can use this conditional statements, also using this framework isn't that bad either.